# Can (slow) Internet speed get you a 500 server error?

Tags: errors, server

Not sure if my host or config fails sometimes or if my slow internet contributes to a server error (500).

Comment: Unlikely, but depends on the Browser, potential proxy servers etc. Look in your browser's developer tools at the request itself, especially at the headers & content of the response. Also look whether the request is in the access log of your server, and with what status it's logged there.

Comment: a 500 error is a server error, it just means "something went wrong, check the error logs to find out what"

Comment: sorry for the downvote, but this has nothing specific to wordpress, at least not as it is phrased right now.

Comment: you could ask me to remove question instead of downvote but ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. 500 error will return when you have server error. PHP error, etc. [See response code reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 500 Internal Server Error
>   server error response code indicates that the server encountered an
>   unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. Sometimes,
>   server administrators log error responses like the 500 status code
>   with more details about the request to prevent the error from
>   happening again in the future.